# Set a different tooltip formatter for each sunburst levels - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I created a sunburst chart with *highcharts*. I set the `config` object given to `Highcharts.chart('type', config)` in python. I want to have one different tooltip for each level of the sunburst chart.

I can do a big js function that search the level of the point in my data then give the level to the tooltip formatter to display the specific data, but that is not suitable I think.

Is there any `highcharts` function to get the point's level or to define the tooltip in `series.levels[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get this based upon the slice's `level` property. You can do something like:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        console.log(this); // see what each slice's properties are
        if (this.point.node.level == 4) {
            return 'Population of <b>' + this.point.options.name +
                   '</b> is <b>' + this.point.options.value + '</b>';
        } else {
            return 'Level <b>' + this.point.node.level + '</b> has no tooltip';
        }
    }
}
```

Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdb56p0o/)

Answer (score 0):

Tank you for your answer wergled. In fact what help me is the `console.log(this)`! I don't know why but `this` refers directly to the point in my code. And since I code in python, I have to format a js function into a python string, this is quite difficult.
So I ended with something like:

```
config['tooltip']['pointFormatter'] = (
      "function(){"
      "var level = this.node.level;"
      "return"
     f" {myValues}[level] + '<span style=\"text-transform: uppercase;font-weight:bold\">{myPythonVar}:</span> '"
      f"+  {myJsFormatter}.call(this) + '<br>'"
      "}"
      )
```

It mixes python and js, it hard to read but needed in my case.